# jQuery structure - clarification?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was [**reading this article about how jQuery works**](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aGgBhD9sDrcoJ%3awww.ebenshapiro.com/2011/04/how-jquery-works/%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk)  , and that article minified jquery structure into symbolic code:

```
/*1*/   var jQuery = (function ()
/*2*/   {
/*3*/   
/*4*/   
/*5*/       var jQuery = function (selector, context)
/*6*/       {
/*7*/   
/*8*/   
/*9*/           return new jQuery.fn.init(selector, context, rootjQuery);
/*10*/       },
/*11*/           rootjQuery;
/*12*/   
/*13*/   
/*14*/       jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
/*15*/           constructor: jQuery,
/*16*/           init: function (selector, context, rootjQuery)
/*17*/           {
/*18*/   
/*19*/               if (!selector)
/*20*/               {
/*21*/                   return this;
/*22*/               }
/*23*/           },
/*24*/           //I screwed with the core! 
/*25*/   
/*26*/           yo: function ()
/*27*/           {
/*28*/               alert("yo")
/*29*/           },
/*30*/       };
/*31*/   
/*32*/       jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn;
/*33*/   
/*34*/       // Expose jQuery to the global object
/*35*/       return jQuery;
/*36*/   })();
```

Line `#32` is where the magic happens. so when I'm writing `jQuery(..)` it actually run `new init()` which has access to all `jQuery.fn` functions.

It's pretty clear (most of it) but I have 2 questions  :

**Question #1** Why does line `#15` (`constructor: jQuery,`) exists ? all it does (imho) is to tell the `prototype` object that it's `ctor function` is `jQuery`. how does jQuery use that fact ?

**Question #2** Looking at line `#14`  , it's obviously adding functions to `jQUery.fn` ( function `yo` in our example  - line `#26`).

But why does `jQuery.prototype` (line #14 middle) **also** have these functions (it sets them to it's `prototype`...)? It's like we're going to do `$.addClass()` which is *invalid*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference of the value, prototype and property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143590/difference-of-the-value-prototype-and-property)

Comment: @Bergi Your answer does not answering question #1 of mine. you just describe the fact. nothing more. regarding Question #2 of mine , I dont understnad your wording there : "_for those who don't use the fn property_" - can u elaborate ?

Comment: Ok, I'll come with a more specific answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does line #15 (`constructor: jQuery,`) exist? all it does (imho) is to tell the prototype object that it's ctor function is jQuery.

Yes. People do expect to find `new jQuery().constructor == jQuery`.

> how does jQuery use that fact ?

For example, the [`pushStack` internal method](http://api.jquery.com/pushStack/) [uses `this.constructor()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2df1aad6a1c9376c2a477eba26ee992113ed1c23/src/core.js#L67) to create new instances - which also allows [inheritance from jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13919931/1048572).

> But why does jQuery.prototype (line #14 middle) also have these [jQuery.fn] functions (it sets them to it's prototype...)?

To cite [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19759489/1048572):

> *One of the reasons behind this is certainly that they want to
>   accomodate people that might modify `jQuery.prototype` instead of
>   `jQuery.fn`.*
>
> *However another valid reason is that they perhaps wanted
>   `somejQueryObj instanceof jQuery` to returns true, while it
>   normally wouldn't.*

> It's like we're going to do `$.addClass()` which is invalid.

No, how so? Are you confusing the standard `.prototype` property of every (constructor) function with the internal prototype chain?

Comment: Regarding your last reply here  - I dont understand.What I mean is : If  the object which has all the functions is being set to `jQuery.fn` - it's fine. but they also set this object which has all the functions into `jQuery.prototype.` - why ? `$(div).addClass()` should not work on `$.addClass()` - am I understood ?

Comment: Why do you think that `jQuery.prototype.addClass = …` would make `$.addClass` work?

Comment: I dont see which line responsible for your demo : `somejQueryObj instanceof jQuery`.  I mean - `somejQueryObj` is like `$()` which inturn is like `new init()` . so where is the connection between `jQuery.fn.init.prototype` to `jQuery.prototype` ( prototype inheritance) - can you show me that path please?

Comment: The connection is `jQuery.fn.init.prototype === jQuery.prototype`…

Comment: Bergi  - All I see in my code is `jQuery.fn.init.prototype=jQuery.fn`. I dont see `x.prototype=y.prototype`...Again , please , can you show me where is that line ? or is it the combination of #32 and #14 ?

Comment: Yes, it's the combination. All those references point to the same object.

Comment: thats the problem.... they do not reference. the object is cloned...no ? since js does not use reference but values

Comment: All objects are [*reference values*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266616/primitive-value-vs-reference-value). Nothing is cloned.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49239/discussion-between-royi-namir-and-bergi)